# Yaml - how to replace key value using sed?

Tags: unix, sed, command-line, yaml, string-parsing

I have a yaml config, and I want to replace one of the fields with a new value?

Here is an example of the yaml config:

```
application: "app_name"
pipeline: "app-pipeline"
parameters:
  spinnaker_environment: "production"
  perform_cleanup: false
  build_image_tag: "foobar"
```

I want to replace "foobar" under the `build_image_tag` field and replace it with a different value like "latest". How do I do this?

I tried the following:

```
sed '/^parameters:/{n;s/build_image_tag:.*/build_image_tag: "latest"/;}' exec.yml
```

But that didn't seem to work. The yaml config should look like this:

```
application: "app_name"
pipeline: "app-pipeline"
parameters:
  spinnaker_environment: "production"
  perform_cleanup: false
  build_image_tag: "latest"
```

Comment: Please, use the right tool for the job, see my answer below =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`go yq`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) or [`python yq`](https://pypi.org/project/yq/), the proper tools:

```
$ yq -i '.parameters.build_image_tag="latest"' file.yaml
application: "app_name"
pipeline: "app-pipeline"
parameters:
  spinnaker_environment: "production"
  perform_cleanup: false
  build_image_tag: "latest"
```

- `yq` use the same syntax than `jq` for `JSON`
- the `-i` is the same as `sed -i`: replace on the fly

Comment: Okay thanks for the suggestion. I would prefer built-in unix packages since I need to run this on Jenkins, but this will do I think. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is an 'S' command in `sed` for this. It works like so:

```
# sed 's/pattern/replacement/[g]' - g is an optional flag to replace all instances

# examples:
echo "a b b c" | sed 's/b/d/'
a d b c

echo "a b b c" | sed 's/b/d/g'
a d d c
```

For your example it would be like this:

```
sed 's/foobar/latest/' exec.yml
```

I'd recommend to create a template file like this to simplify things:

```
cat template.yml
application: "_APP_"
pipeline: "_PIP_"
parameters:
  spinnaker_environment: "_ENV_"
  perform_cleanup: _CLN_
  build_image_tag: "_IMG_"
```

and change it with `sed` like so:

```
sed '
  s/_APP_/app_name/;
  s/_PIP_/app-pipeline/;
  s/_ENV_/production/;
  s/_CLN_/false/;
  s/_IMG_/latest/;
' template.yml > new.yml
```

Using vars:

```
app=app_name
pip=app-pipeline
env=production
cln=false
img=latest

sed "
  s/_APP_/$app/;
  s/_PIP_/$pip/;
  s/_ENV_/$env/;
  s/_CLN_/$cln/;
  s/_IMG_/$img/;
" template.yml > new.yml
```